# Redirecting a HTML form to an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm testing out some code at the moment and basically attempting to redirect a HTML form to an AJAX call (POST) which displays the response of a script running on my server.

**HTML**

```
<form id='form' name='qform' method='post' action='./resources/comment-redirect.php'>

<input type='search' name='name' class='comment-instance' autofocus='autofocus' value='name' />

<input type='search' name='email' class='comment-instance' autofocus='autofocus' value='email (not published)' />

<TEXTAREA name='comment-box' class='comment-instance' COLS=60 ROWS=5 value='email' />

<button type='submit' id='comment-submit' value='Submit'>--SUBMIT--</button>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#comment-submit').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         console.log("User clicked");
         jQuery.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url: './resources/comment-redirect.php',
             data: {'name':$('[name=name]').val().toString(), 'email':$('[name=email]').val().toString(), 'comment':$('[name=comment-box]').val().toString() },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(result){
             console.log(result);
            }

         }); //end of JQuery.Ajax()



//PHP
if( !empty($_GET['a'] ) )
{
    print("This request has been routed to GET\n");
}
else if( !empty($_POST) )
{
    print("This request has been routed to POST\n");
    print($_POST);
}
else
{
    print("Other");
}
```

So at the moment, in the console window I get 'User clicked', meaning that the callback does work - however there is no AJAX response. I've used a browser and manually tested my PHP script and that passes as well (both GET and POST). So for some reason this Ajax call doesn't seem to be firing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated Stack.

Comment: Check your console, specifically the Network tab, is the request going thru?

Comment: "So for some reason this Ajax call doesn't seem to be firing." u mean not output for  console.log(result); ?

Comment: Yes, the console.log(result) doesn't give any output.

Comment: (CONSOLE ~ NETWORK)
comment-redirect.php
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery.js:9597
Script

Comment: check the 'dataType' response, maybe the ajax is called but the dataType is wrong!

Comment: Is the code to the php file you're calling available? If so could you post it below so that we can see what's going on in there?

Comment: @PabloWeb18

Thank you so much, the problem was with the dataType property in the initial Ajax call. Thanks to your suggestion I took another look at the JQuery Documentation, and lo and below - the data type is for the response that the code expects back.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped :) @MeMoryLEAk99

Answer (score 0):

You have set `type:'POST'` in your ajax request but on the serverside you are trying to get the sent data from `$_GET`, so at first, in your `php` code, you don't need to check the `$_GET` array because you know that, you are sending data to `$_POST` array.

You have this

```
data: {
    'name':$('[name=name]').val().toString(),
    'email':$('[name=email]').val().toString(),
    'comment':$('[name=comment-box]').val().toString()
}
```

Just get rid of `.toString()`, it's already string, even if a text box contains a numeric value, it's being treated as string.

You have `dataType: 'json'` but you are not printing `json string`, a `json string` looks something like this

```
'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

So, your complete code (jQuery) should look like this

```
$('#comment-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("User clicked");
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
         url:'./resources/comment-redirect.php',
         data:{
             'name':$('[name=name]').val(),
             'email':$('[name=email]').val(),
             'comment':$('[name=comment-box]').val()
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result){
              // Will output a JavaScript object (if a json string is returned)
             console.log(result);
         }
     });
});
```

On the server side, if you don't return (print) a `json string` then change `dataType` to `html` or return a valid `json string` using something like this

```
echo json_encode(array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'));
```

So, in your `success` callback, you'll get a `JavaScript` object and can use it like

```
success:function(result){
    console.log(result.key1); // will output value1
    console.log(result.key2); // will output value2
}
```

If the `url` is correct then it should work. Depending on your current code, it could be

```
if( !empty($_POST) )
{
    // everything in $_POST array will be encoded as a json string
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

If you want to add

```
print("This request has been routed to POST\n");
```

in your `json string`, then you can try this

```
$_POST['msg'] = 'This request has been routed to POST';
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

In the success callback, you can get the string (msg) like this

```
console.log(result.msg); // will output "This request has been routed to POST"
```

Comment: Just for clarification, I use the PHP script above for testing purposes -- to see whether my request was indeed a HTTP GET or POST.